# sed (awk?) to remove nearly duplicate lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that alternates HTML-style comments with its real text:

```
<!-- Here's a first line -->
Here's a first line
<!-- Here's a second line -->
Here's a third line
```

If a comment is identical to the following line apart from the tags themselves, I want to delete it, but otherwise leave it:

```
Here's a first line
<!-- Here's a second line -->
Here's a third line
```

I've read the similar questions here, but been unable to extrapolate the solutions to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/^<!-- \(.*\) -->$/N;s/^<!-- \(.*\) -->\n\1$/\1/'
#
#    /^<!-- \(.*\) -->$/   match an HTML comment as its own line, in which case
#                       N; add the next line to the pattern space and keep going
# 
#                         s/^<!-- \(.*\) -->\n\1$/     detect a comment as you
#                                                 \1/  described and replace it
#                                                      appropriately
```

As shown:

```
$ sed '/^<!-- \(.*\) -->$/N;s/^<!-- \(.*\) -->\n\1$/\1/' <<EOF
> <!-- Foo -->
> Foo
> <!-- Bar -->
> Baz
> <!-- Quux -->
> Quux
> 
> Something
> Something
> Another something
> EOF
```

Gives:

```
Foo
<!-- Bar -->
Baz
Quux

Something
Something
Another something
```

You may need to tweak this to handle indentation, but that shouldn't be too surprising. You may also want to switch to `sed -r`, which will require the that the parentheses are NOT escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '/<!--.*?-->/{h=$0; gsub(/ *(<!--|-->) */, ""); s=$0; next}
      $0!=s{$0=h ORS $0} 1' file.html
Here's a first line
<!-- Here's a second line -->
Here's a third line
```

Comment: The `?` in `/<!--.*?-->/` is doing nothing AFAIK. If it is doing something - what?

Comment: Yes that's right I think `.*?` is behaving same `.*` here.

Comment: I just don't know what awk is treating the `?` in that statement as. I'd have thought maybe a literal `?` but apparently not. It also can't be treating `*?` as zero or 1 occurrences of a literal `*` or the whole regexp wouldn't match any input. I guess it's treating it as zero or 1 occurrences of the 0 or more repetitions of any character that the `.*` represents, i.e. the same as `(.*)?` which is useless but at least not meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;/<!-- (.*) -->\n\1$/!P;D' file
```

This compares all consecutive lines throughout the file for the requested condition and if found does not print the first line of the pair.

N.B. This caters for consecutive comment lines